# Citing a Handbook with no author

Tags: biblatex, citing

Google says:

```
@article{department2019handbook,
  title={The handbook to the NHS Constitution: for England},
  author={Department of Health and Social Care},
  year={2019}
}
```

but for some reason when I try this I get

> of Health D, Care S (2019) The handbook to the nhs constitution: for england.

I need it to look like:

> Department of Health (2019). The handbook to the NHS Constitution: for England.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`and` is a keyword to separate authors as in

```
author={Smith and Jones}
```

so

```
  author={Department of Health and Social Care},
```

is two authors,

author 1 first name Department, surname "of Health"

author 2 first name Social, surname Care

use

```
  author={{Department of Health and Social Care}},
```

Comment: Thank you so much